What do I need to seal interior door?
This sounds trivial but doesn’t seem to. In Europe, even interior doors are properly sealed but not so in the US.
This is problematic for my rooms that go to unconditioned rooms (like basement or garage).
The gap between the door and the frame is less than a millimeter when closed. I tried all kinds of FrostKing seals from HomeDepot but even the “smallest” one is too thick to close the door once installed.
Curiously I couldn’t find a product dedicated to exactly this application
What is the right way and what to get?

Maybe weather stripping that fits on the edge instead being push against.  Usually like a rubber strip that the door will bend away a bit instead of squeezing.

Yep, could try the fuzzy type that's used for sliding doors and windows.

A door to an unconditioned space should be an exterior-type door (and the one to the garage should be a fire-rated door.)

There are styles of weatherstripping that attach to the door stops, and the position is adjusted such that it just meets the door to provide the necessary seal.
Here is an example of Frost King from Home Depot, but there are probably other manufacturers that make this same style.


If the gap is uniform then you could try adjusting the strike plate that the door latch engages with in order to increase the gap, to make room for weather seal, or decrease the gap for a tighter fit. If the strike plate is not adjustable you may be able to replace it with an adjustable strike. Here are some examples. You may of course need to edit the door jamb with a wood chisel to make room for the adjustable strike.  Pick one that will fit your door.
https://www.amazon.com/adjustable-strike-plate/s?k=adjustable+strike+plate
